# Divide a function value by a number

Tags: javascript, function, input, divide

I want to be able to take the value from the calcOrderTotal input and then divide it and display the divided output in another input (for example, to show the Order Total price, and then what the order total 36 monthly lease price would be).  I sort of attempted to do it with the "calc36Month" function, but I know it's not right.

```
function calcOrderTotal() {

var orderTotal = 0;

var productSubtotal = $("#product-subtotal").val() || 0;
var serverPrice = $('.server-radio:checked').val() || 0;
var equipmentPrice = $('.equipment-radio:checked').val() || 0;
var underTotal = $("#under-box").val() || 0;

var orderTotal = parseFloat(CleanNumber(productSubtotal)) + parseFloat(CleanNumber(serverPrice)) + parseFloat(CleanNumber(equipmentPrice));    

$("#order-total").val(CommaFormatted(orderTotal));

$("#fc-price").attr("value", orderTotal);

}
```

The calcOrderTotal function is then redirected to this HTML input and displays a dollar value (this does work):

```
<input type="text" class="total-box" value="$0" id="order-total" disabled="disabled" name="order-total"></input>
```

I want to be able to take the OrderTotal dollar value and divide it by 36 months and input the 36 month lease value into another input.  Here is an example of what I'm looking for (I know this does not work):

```
function calc36Month() {

    var 36Month = 0;

    var orderTotal = $("#order-total").val() || 0;

    var 36Month = parseFloat(CleanNumber(orderTotal)) / 36;    

    $("#36-monthly-total").val(CommaFormatted(36Month));

    $("#fc-price").attr("value", 36Month);

}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: If you think we're going to read that wall of code without any clue of what that's supposed to do, you're out of luck. Reduce the code to the meaningful parts, please.

Comment: @MaxArt - I edited my original question which hopefully is more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ya go:

```
function calcOrderTotal() {
    var orderTotal = 0;

    var productSubtotal = $("#product-subtotal").val() || 0;
    var serverPrice = $('.server-radio:checked').val() || 0;
    var equipmentPrice = $('.equipment-radio:checked').val() || 0;
    var underTotal = $("#under-box").val() || 0;

    var orderTotal = parseFloat(CleanNumber(productSubtotal)) + parseFloat(CleanNumber(serverPrice)) + parseFloat(CleanNumber(equipmentPrice));    

    $("#order-total").val(CommaFormatted(orderTotal));
    $("#fc-price").attr("value", orderTotal);
    if (orderTotal > 0) {
        calcMonthly(orderTotal);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Edited per request.

```
function calcMonthly(total) {
    var pmt1 = total / 36;
    var pmt2 = total / 24;
    var pmt3 = total / 12;
    $("#monthly-36").val(CommaFormatted(pmt1));
    $("#monthly-24").val(CommaFormatted(pmt2));
    $("#monthly-12").val(CommaFormatted(pmt3));
    //$("#fc-price").attr("value", pmt1); // what is the purpose of this?
}
```

Avoid using numeric digits as variable names, element ID's or CSS classes, or beginning any of the aforementioned references with a number. Begin all variable names, ID's and classes with a letter.

Comment: Thank you @Lazerblade.  If I'm also going to add another input for 24 months and 12 months, how would I add that to this script as well?  I'm not sure what the $("#fc-price").attr("value", pmt); line is for.  I did not originally write this script and I don't know much about JavaScript.  I'm just trying to edit it to my boss's requirements.  I can post the entire JS file if you like.

Comment: Add additional inputs, and simply give them new ID's (#monthly-2yr, #monthly-1yr, etc...) then calculate the totals for those accordingly. I'll add an edit to show these.

Comment: for some reason the function does not work when adding pmt2 and pmt3 to it.  It works well though with just pmt1.  I will make sure I didn't mistype anything...